# How to upload data and string to sderver [Swift,Php]

Tags: php, swift

In my swift app I've the following function:

```
func imageUploadRequest(imageView: UIImageView, uploadUrl: NSURL, param: [String:String]?) {

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:uploadURL! as URL);
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let postParameters = "email=" + String(email)
    request.httpBody = postParameters.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let boundary = generateBoundaryString()
    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView1.image!, 1.0)
    if (imageData == nil)  { return }

    request.httpBody = createBodyWithParameters(parameters: param, filePathKey: "file", imageDataKey: imageData! as NSData, boundary: boundary) as Data

    let task =  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if let data = data {

            _ =  try!JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

        } else if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

func createBodyWithParameters(parameters: [String: String]?, filePathKey: String?, imageDataKey: NSData, boundary: String) -> NSData {
        let body = NSMutableData();

```
    if parameters != nil {
        for (key, value) in parameters! {
            body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")
            body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
            body.appendString(string: "\(value)\r\n")
        }
    }

    let filename = profilePicturePath
    let mimetype = "image/jpg"

    body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")
    body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filePathKey!)\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
    body.appendString(string: "Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
    body.append(imageDataKey as Data)
    body.appendString(string: "\r\n")
    body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)--\r\n")

    return body
}

func generateBoundaryString() -> String {
    return "Boundary-\(NSUUID().uuidString)"
}

func downloadImage(url: URL) {

    getDataFromUrl(url: url) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
        print(response?.suggestedFilename ?? url.lastPathComponent)
        DispatchQueue.main.async() {
            self.imageView1.image = UIImage(data: data)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

> > USER_IMG_SET.php

```
$email = $_POST['email'];

//$email = "galileogalilei@yahoo.com";

$target_dir = "../usersAccountData/".$email;

if(!file_exists($target_dir)) {
mkdir($target_dir, 0755, true);
}

$target_dir = $target_dir . "/" . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir)) {
echo json_encode([
"Message" => "The file ". basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.",
"Status" => "OK",
"userId" => $_REQUEST["userId"]
]);

} else {

echo json_encode([
"Message" => "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.",
"Status" => "Error",
"userId" => $_REQUEST["userId"]
]);

}
```

I uploaded image data and I also want to upload the user email in php ($email = $_POST['email'];) with the same request.
How can I do it?

Because I don't have other details to write!
« Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. »

Comment: You are not showing the definition of `createBodyWithParameters(parameters:filePathKey:imageDataKey:boundary:)`. Also, you are not showing how you are calling your `imageUploadRequest(imageView:uploadUrl:param:)`. You may need to pass `["email": email]` to `param:`, when calling the method.

Answer (score 0):

```
request.httpBody = createBodyWithParameters(parameters: param, filePathKey: "file", imageDataKey: imageData! as NSData, boundary: boundary) as Data
```

here param will contain imageData and **imageDataKey** would be key name for server

Comment: Thank you but I don't understood, can you explain me better?

Comment: see for image first you have to specify the key at server end for that you are going to get the image. then in params imageData would picked against that key only